# Can data remain incorrupt and integrity if take snapshot in a busy database in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup, google-compute-engine, database-backups

We install our own MySQL in GCE and we are thinking to use GCE snapshot as a backup solution. As our MySQL database is quite busy, we would like to know if taking snapshot on it while still in production, can the data be incorrupt and remain integrity in the snapshot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Best Practices for Persistent Disk Snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#prepare_for_consistency) documentation, if your database is in use during snapshot you may have some data loss.

If you don't have too many write but lots of read, that could do the trick as the chance of loosing new datas will be smaller, but that's still not a 100% sure thing.

Comment: Please delete your answer as this is bad advice. Do NOT snapshot live systems unless the OS specifically supports snapshots. I have written shapshotting code for both Linux and Windows and the number of details that must be implemented is significant. Google does not recommend snapshots on live systems and warns about potential data loss.

Comment: Please do read what I wrote (I also put the link to the best practice)... I never said it's safe, and never said it should be done... I said it could be done and it can... After that it's juste a matter of how much you care for you datas and if you are ready to loose some...

Comment: I am asking you to delete your answer. Recommending any process that can result in data loss or corruption is ill-advised no matter what "warnings" you attach. Best practices mean you don't recommend bad-practices.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I would like to know more about the meaning of data loss. I care if the data is exactly at a point of time of the disks. As it is a MySQL database, if a snapshot is just like power outage suddenly, this should be ok as innodb can recover for itself. I afraid the data is not consistent.

Comment: It won't be like a power outage, the snapshot will have corrupted datas if the datas is being written and the snapshot is launched you may have some missing parts and that would make your snapshot inconsistent.

Comment: understood. That means it is not a suitable solution to backup a heavy write disks like MySQL. May be I need to do by a manual script then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it can be a arguable but working solution only if your database is mainly used to read datas, not write them...